# How to fix 'TypeError: argument of type 'function' is not iterable' in python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I was making a django app which would be able to send and receive emails. For the django app I was writing the code for views.py
After I ran the file, I got stuck with this error.
This is the views.py from my django app

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib import messages
from django.core.mail import send_mail
#from demoapp.form import ContactForm


# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return render(request,'index.html',{'page':'home'})


def contact(request):
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ContactForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                send_mail(form.cleaned_data)
                messages.success(request,'Your message is successfully submitted')

        else:
            form = ContactForm()

    except:
        messages.error(request,'contact.html',{'page':'contact','form':form})

def clear(request):
    form = ContactForm()
    messages.error(request,'Fields Cleared')
    return render(request,'contact.html',{'page':'contact','form':form})
```

**Urls.py**
This urls.py is from the django project. I havent created any urls.py for my app.

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from demoapp.views import index,about,contact,clear
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$' , index , name=index),
    url(r'^about/$' , about , name=about),
    url(r'^contact/$' , contact , name=contact),
    url(r'^clear/$' , clear , name=clear),


]
```

After I run python3 manage.py runserver I get the following error

```sh
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 399, in check
    messages.extend(check_resolver(pattern))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 325, in check
    warnings = self._check_pattern_name()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 333, in _check_pattern_name
    if self.pattern.name is not None and ":" in self.pattern.name:
TypeError: argument of type 'function' is not iterable
```

Comment: can you add your urls.py?

Comment: There is probably something wrong with your `urls.py`.

Comment: Do you have a function called `name`, somewhere in your code?

Comment: The `clear` view is also somewhat "strange". One typically does not do that through a view. Typically this is done in the HTML/JavaScript.

Comment: Note also that `contact` never returns a response.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have added the urls.py file

Comment: @JPG I have added the urls.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `name`s are not strings, but references to the view *functions*. You should use strings instead, like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$' , index , name='index'),
    url(r'^about/$' , about , name='about'),
    url(r'^contact/$' , contact , name='contact'),
    url(r'^clear/$' , clear , name='clear'),
]
```

So we here use a *string literal* `'index'` instead of the `index` identifier, which just refers to the view function.