# Python Django issue with makemigrations

Tags: python, django

I'm new at Django but recently I've been having some errors when entering the `python manage.py makemigrations` command.

I tried to understand my mistake by reading the following log but I really can't:

```
Migrations for 'main':
  main\migrations\0004_main_about.py
    - Add field about to main
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Nyro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Nyro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Nyro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 341, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "C:\Users\Nyro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 230, in close_all
    connection.close()
  File "C:\Users\Nyro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nyro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 261, in close
    if not self.is_in_memory_db():
  File "C:\Users\Nyro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 380, in is_in_memory_db
    return self.creation.is_in_memory_db(self.settings_dict['NAME'])
  File "C:\Users\Nyro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\creation.py", line 12, in is_in_memory_db
    return database_name == ':memory:' or 'mode=memory' in database_name
TypeError: argument of type 'WindowsPath' is not iterable
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [return database\_name == ':memory:' or 'mode=memory' in database\_name TypeError: argument of type 'WindowsPath' is not iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64046773/return-database-name-memory-or-mode-memory-in-database-name-typeerror)

Comment: Can u provide your database settings and models.py?

Comment: This type of error are come in two situation = 1> Error in urls.py =>Path Error [check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56148087/how-to-fix-typeerror-argument-of-type-function-is-not-iterable-in-python) , 2> Error in models.py file (Provide Your Model code to solve Error)

Comment: I solved by changing 'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3' to 'NAME': str(BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3')